# Looking for a solution to an issue, where screen goes blank after upgrading an old laptop to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown, hibernate, toshiba-laptop

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem, regardless of how many suggestions I have found from searching the web.

I am currently using a spare **Toshiba Sattelite Pro R50-B-12U**, which after having upgraded it with an SSD and also having upgraded it from windows 8 pro to 10 Professional, I seem to have been facing a weird issue occurring with the laptop.

The issue is, every time the computer tries to turn off; whether its from shutdown, hibernation, sleep or screen turn off from closing the lid, it seems to turn off the actual screen, but before completely going off it seems to freeze up, and at this point, when I attempt to press the power button, it just remains in the same state, without turning off.

The only way I get it to start again is by force shutting down the laptop (by pressing and holding the power button) and then turning it on works again, but in this case, if I hibernated, or the computer went to sleep, then essentially I lose all my open applications/ data.

I have been facing this issue for over 3 weeks now and since then I have tried several solutions I found from google search results, from disabling wifi wake lock to disabling fast startup, however, none of this issues have resolved the issue I face.

If you require any more details, please ask, and I will try my best to provide the details for you.

Comment: @Ramhound Thankyou very much, let me attempt to reinstall the driver with a windows 10 compatible one, I believe the current drivers are the ones automatically installed by windows.

Comment: @fixer1234 I guess its not really that relevant, let me remove it. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: @Ramhound I essentially ran intel update utility, and found that the latest graphic driver would not update due current driver being the manufacturer recomended driver. Therefore, to test your theory, using this guide: https://steamcommunity.com/app/233250/discussions/2/558749190911446231/ , I was able to overwrite the manufacturer recomended drver, and replace it with the latest intel provided driver. After installing and restarting I tested hibernation which seemed to work perfectly, so seems ok for now. I will reply again in a few days to confirm if it is really fixed. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Ramhound just wanted to update you, no the problem has not been fixed, it still keeps happening and therefore I am not sure if it is the graphic drivers that are the issue.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this particular issue, can somebody please assist me. I am happy to provide any logs, but please tell me which in particular as I am not aware. Thank you.